# One To Many (UniDirectional) Add Method On-One Side Gives Error

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, rest, one-to-many

Error is:

> at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy106.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at
> com.example.OneToManyUniDirectional.service.concretes.AuthorManager.addAuthor(AuthorManager.java:50)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> com.example.OneToManyUniDirectional.controller.AuthorController.addAuthors(AuthorController.java:21)
> ~[classes/:an]

I have no idead why this happening.

Author class:

```
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="surname")
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Book> books=new HashSet<>();
    
}
```

Book Class:

```
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String isbn;
    @Column(name="book_name")
    private String name;
}
```

addAuthor method

```
    @Override
        public void addAuthor(CreateAuthor createAuthor){
          //  Book book=new Book();
   Author author=new Author();
            author.setFirstName(createAuthor.getFirstName());
            author.setLastName(createAuthor.getLastName());
            if(this.bookRepository.findById(createAuthor.getBook().getId()).isPresent()){
                UpdateBook updateBook=new UpdateBook();
                updateBook.setName(createAuthor.getBook().getName());
                updateBook.setIsbn(createAuthor.getBook().getIsbn());
                this.bookService.updateBook(updateBook,createAuthor.getBook().getId());
            }
            else{
    
                CreateBook createBook=new CreateBook();
                createBook.setName(createAuthor.getBook().getName());
                createBook.setIsbn(createAuthor.getBook().getIsbn());
                this.bookService.addBook(createBook);
 author.getBooks().add(createAuthor.getBook());
            }
         
           
            this.authorRepository.save(author);
        }
```

Create Author:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CreateAuthor {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Book book;
}
```

Controller

```
  @PostMapping("/authors")
    public void addAuthors(@RequestBody CreateAuthor createAuthor){
        this.authorService.addAuthor(createAuthor);
    }
```

Also create book and  updateBook classes does not has id properties in it.

Comment: i will add example repo but i want my dto as above not like in repo thanks

Comment: I called REST services in the swagger-ui, I did not see any error. reproducer suppose to throw the error in the question. otherwise it is not reproducer.

Comment: Please post the whole exception with a message and a full stack trace, not just a random part of it.